# HtmlPurifier - Codeblock

Tags: parsing, tags, htmlpurifier

I was looking in HtmlPurifier documentation, but I can't see nothing about that.

Let's say I have

```
<div class="codebox">
All html tags here - Even <div class="codebox">another code box</div>
</div>
```

I want to parse the content of the first `<div class="codebox">` so it can be readable as plaintext.

Can htmlpurifier do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box HTMLPurifier can't do that and there is no config setting, that I know of, that can convert only the first `<div>` tag to plain text without converting the entire document. And even for converting the entire document to text the HTMLPurifier is neither needed nor recommended.
You can extend functionality of HTMLPurifier but unless you are an expert coder, I wouldn't recommend doing that.
However if you want to convert a part of the HTML document to text then break it into parts and run the part which you want to convert to text through

```
strip_tags()
```

PHP Manual page on [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

You could convert all the div tags in your document to plain text with this configuration directive:

```
$config->set(HTML.ForbiddenElements, 'div'); //This will black list 'div' tag
```

And if you absolutely insist on converting your entire document to text using HTMLPurifier then here is the config directive that will do that.

```
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', ''); //This will white list NO tags ''
```